# Angular Material Dynamically define theme

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-material, themes

I am rewriting an AngularJS application where the theme of the application is provided by the server. Also the theme can be edited by the user within the application (via color pickers).

This was possible via the `ng.material.IThemingProvider` and the `$mdTheming` from Angularjs material. But In Angular those services do not exist. So that leaves me with the question, *how can I dynamically create an Angular Material theme and use it?*

---

**The server response**

I am getting the following data from the server:

```
"css": {
    "--nav-font-color-accent": "#fff",
    "--nav-font-color-active": "#fff",
    "--primary": "#4f2d7f",
    "--nav-background": "#fefffe",
    "--nav-font-color": "#47a742",
    "--warn": "#ff5722",
    "--accent": "#00a8b5",
    "--brand-color": "#47a742"
}
```

This data is then converted to an Angularjs-material theme via the `ng.material.IThemingProvider`:

```
 this.themeProvider.definePalette('primaryPalette', this.generatePalette(config['--primary']));
 this.themeProvider.theme('default')
          .primaryPalette('primaryPalette')
```

---

Is there a way I can reproduce this functionality in Angular Material `7.1.0`?

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem, were you able to solve this? Is there any way a customer overwrites a default theme during runtime?

Comment: @AlejandroGonzález, The only solution I could find is implementing my own theme service. This was due to the fact that Angular Material only reads themes that were defined via scss. There is also no ETA on the feature to support dynamic theme loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular Material2 you can dynamically *apply* themes, but you cannot dynamically *generate* themes because theming is done using SASS which requires compilation in order to generate usable CSS.

Comment: So that would mean that it isn't possible to generate and apply themes on the fly?

Comment: As I already stated, you **can** dynamically _apply_. You **cannot** dynamically _generate_. So if you want to dynamically apply theme changes, they would have to be pre-generated. The [Angular Material demo site](https://material.angular.io/) itself does this ('select a theme' icon on right side of top toolbar).

Comment: hmm thats a bummer. A lot of clients use this functionality in our current application (AngularJS Material). So that would mean we need to find an other way. 

Thanks for the answer!